# Scaling relation of potential energy per particle of Rashba Spin Orbit Coupled (SOC) 2D electron gas for short and long range interactions

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, fourier-transform, electronic-band-theory

I am trying to prove the scaling relations of potential energy per particle($V(\vec{r}) = \frac{V_0}{|\vec{r}|^\alpha}$) of Rashba Spin Orbit Coupled (SOC) 2D electron gas in uniform liquid phase for short($\alpha>2$) and long range($\alpha<2$) interactions as shown in the "Electronic liquid crystalline phases in a spin-orbit coupled two-dimensional electron gas" by Erez Berg, Mark S. Rudner, and Steven A. Kivelson https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.035116. The picture from the text is attached below-

[image]

I transformed my integral to Fourier space which resulted in the following expression
\begin{equation}
\bar{\varepsilon}_{pot} = \frac{1}{2n\Omega}\sum_{\vec{k}_1,\vec{k}_2}\sum_{\vec{q}}v_\vec{q}\langle c^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}_1+\vec{q}}c^{\dagger}_{\vec{k}_2-\vec{q}}c_{\vec{k}_2}c_{\vec{k}_1}\rangle
\end{equation}
Where $v_q$ is Fourier transform of repulsive potential $V(\vec{r})$. On averaging over the annular fermi sea(AFS) we get
\begin{equation}
= \frac{1}{2n\Omega}\sum_{(\vec{k}_1,\vec{k}_2)\in AFS}\sum_{\vec{q}}(v_0\delta_{\vec{q},0} - v_{|\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2|}\delta_{\vec{q},\vec{k}_1-\vec{k}_2})
\end{equation}
I am not sure how to compute the Fourier transformation for any $\alpha$ as it results in diverging integral.